# How can I move a document's array to an array of arrays of the same document in mongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

The code I'm currently using is the following:

```
findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: pollId, storeId },
            {
                $push: {
                    previousAnswers: {
                        allAnswers: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$currentAnswers.allAnswers",
                                as: "answer",
                                in: "$$answer"
                            }
                        },
                        beguinningDate: "$currentAnswers.beguinningDate"
                    }
                },
                $unset: {
                    currentAnswers: 1
                },
                $set: {
                    isPublic: false
                }
            }
        )
```

The idea would be that the current answers attibute (which is an object that holds an array) resets (in this case disappears) and it's backup is pushed to the previousAnswers array. The problem is I don't really know how to move the answers array correctly (as you can see I am trying to do it with a map, but it does not seem to be working). I don't know if this adds anything, but I am using mongoose in node.

An example of what I want to do would be the following:

The document I have

```
"previousAnswers": [],
"isPublic": true,
"currentAnswers": {
    "beguinningDate": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "0"
        }
    },    
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d6dd7c088fad142ed3ece0"
    },
    "allAnswers": [
        {
            "userId": "62d69bf6004cbf8a927070c7",
            "userAnswers": [
                0,
                [0],
                "0",
                0,
                true,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "language": "dasdasd",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "62d6dda1088fad142ed3ece4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The document that I want to have after the update:

```
"previousAnswers": [
    {
        "beguinningDate": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "0"
            }
        },    
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62d6dd7c088fad142ed3ece0"
        },
        "allAnswers": [
            {
                "userId": "62d69bf6004cbf8a927070c7",
                "userAnswers": [
                    0,
                    [0],
                    "0",
                    0,
                    true,
                    1,
                    1,
                    1,
                    0
                ],
                "language": "dasdasd",
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "62d6dda1088fad142ed3ece4"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"isPublic": false
```

Comment: if you can give a sample document in json, and the expected output after the update

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with what you asked for